# Initiate a Work Flow Every 24 hrs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I have the need to initiate THE MOST SIMPLE ACTION possible every 24hrs in an SP List. The action doesn't even have to do or mean anything, just kick-off in a way that it impacts the entire SP list; this in-turn (is my hope), would initiate cascading actions that also update existing 'Current Date'(calculated column) and 'Compliance Status' (calculated column).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2013 platform workflow, then you may try to create a workflow has a loop which will not end and put a pause 24 hrs action in side the loop. So each time the loop runs will wait for 24 hrs then start the next run

Comment: Yes, sir. This is what I assumed, based on my limited skill set; this is the issue.

I do not know where or how to create such a flow in SP. Is there a link to the process that can get me to my destination?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh if you are using flow, things will be much easier as we can have the recurrence trigger:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks